# Why my javascript isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this working code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bandom</title>
    <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link href="bandom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <textarea maxlength="50" id="field1"></textarea>
    <div id="field2"></div>
    <script src="bandom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I call my `.js` file in the beginning in the head tag, javascript is not working. Why?

All my javascript do, is counting symbols.

```
$('#field1').keyup(function () {
    var left = 50 - $(this).val().length;
    $('#field2').text('Characters left: ' + left);
});
```

I had like plenty of projects, in some the position of javascript doesn't matter, but in some it does. Can anyone explain this to me.

Comment: Is there a console error you care to provide?

Comment: F12 opens the developer's console, the answer is probably there.

Comment: More people would be willing to look at this if you have a jsfiddle prepared.

Comment: *"But when I call my .js file in the beginning in the head tag..."* I'm confused. In your quoted code, it's **not** in the beginning in the head tag, it's in the body (where it should be). ???

Comment: FYI "not working" doesn't tell us jack. Like literally nothing.

Comment: We don't do the "EDIT: Answered..." thing on SO. Instead, when the question is at least 15 minutes old, tick the checkmark next to the answer that answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I call my .js file in the beginning in the head tag, javascript is not working. Why?

The code within a `script` tag is run *immediately* when that tag is encountered in the markup (unless you use the `defer` or `async` attributes on the `script` tag.)

So if the `script` tag is in the `head` and you're trying to make use of elements defined later in the body, they don't exist when the code runs. In your case, the code:

```
$("#field1").keyup(function() { /*...*/});
```

...doesn't find any elements, and so doesn't hook up any handlers.

When the `script` tag is *below* the element in the markup (as in your quoted code), the element exists and so it can be found and used.

[Best practice](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) is to put your `script` tags at the bottom of the body, just before the closing `</body>` element. If you can't do that for some reason, second choice is to use jQuery's [`ready` function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Or since it's jquery just wrap it with the document ready function

Comment: ...but he loads the script after the elements appear in the source.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Yeah, see my question on the question. (And hit refresh, I address this in the answer as well.)

Comment: I see, he says the issue is only when the script is loaded in the head tag. So yep. Wish it was easier to find one of the million dupes of this question.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: At least this one puts a spin on it a bit, with the code block putting the script elsewhere. :-)

Comment: Great answer, I wish I had your patience. Something I need to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#field1').keyup(function () {
        var left = 50 - $(this).val().length;
        $('#field2').text('Characters left: ' + left);
    });
}
```

Comment: oh well, just noticed your edited question. Guess you figured it out already :/